# Find position of instance of class in a list

Tags: python, list, class

Given a class, say

```
class Complex:
    def __init__(self, realpart, imagpart):
        self.r = realpart
        self.i = imagpart
```

I would like to find the position in a list of an instance of this class. For instance, given

```
list = [1, 2, 3, Complex(1, 1)]
```

how can I find the position of `Complex(1, 1)`?

I tried `list.index(Complex(1, 1))`, but the object created from the second call to `Complex` is not the same as the first, so this results in a `ValueError` exception being raised.

How could I do this?

More generally, how could I find the position in a list of any instances of `Complex` (e.g. for `list = [1, Complex(1, 1), 2, Complex(2, 2)]` to return `1` and `3`)?

Comment: You can use `isinstance(x, Complex)` as your condition, in place of the `x<a or x>b`.

Comment: @Rawing Do you think it would be better that I remove the "More generally, ..." part of the post in order to not mark the question as duplicate? CoryKramer's answer and your comment point to `isinstance`, which was the important part that I was missing and that helped me. (See also my comment under CoryKramer's answer for what I had in mind about the "More generally, ..." part.)

Comment: It's not for me to say if you should rewrite your question. There's nothing wrong with your question being a duplicate, so you should ask your question as accurately as possible; there's no reason to try and avoid getting it marked as a dupe. And if the duplicate I found didn't accurately answer your question, we can probably find a better one. Or, if you don't think it's a duplicate, you should explain why.

Comment: @Rawing I see, then I will leave it as is. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the `__eq__` method for your class, which is what you'll use for any equality operators. This will allow `list.index` to work as you intended.

```
class Complex:
    def __init__(self, realpart, imagpart):
        self.r = realpart
        self.i = imagpart
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Complex):
            return self.r == other.r and self.i == other.i
        else:
            return False
```

Example

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, Complex(1, 1)]
>>> l.index(Complex(1, 1))
3
```

Comment: Thanks CoryKramer. This also helps answering my more general question (I would replace `self.r == other.r ...` by `True`, and use, e.g., `Complex(_, _)` instead of `Complex(1, 1)`).